# Android Studio can't open emulator and show“invalid GPU mode ‘angle9’；

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, gpu, mode

the other days i changed the GPU mode at OpenGLES to resolve an error but create new problem and cant open emulator  i try to change mode ————AVD manager->right click->open on disk->hw.GPU.mode  but it doesn't work  ,and  i try to remove all Andriod Studio include emulator  but still have this kind of error . the error log have several advice but i dont understand 。that is awful！！

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with emulator and finally solved it by add:

`set PATH=%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%PATH%` 
in environment variables

I hope it helps you

Comment: thanks ！but just this line does not work.... i hope i can follow your Facebook or twitter for more info

Comment: thanks bro! i find a way！！！  1.set environment variables  name:ANDROID_HOME path:your SDK dir  2.at the dir of avd use cmd  3. use order  "emulator -list-avds" to find the name of emulator    4.use “emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host” to open emulator  5.change and resolve